# Find_element works, but find_elements doesn't

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm learning selenium and tried to get all elements that has class name 'rg_i Q4LuWd'

and when I run

```
elements = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "rg_i.Q4LuWd")
print(elements)
```

it works fine and gives

```
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e8a8eba1d97d5651671a81bfd34a63e1", element="4E1CDA74A4AD1CE797AEA8D69D87D383_element_52")>
```

but when i run

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "rg_i.Q4LuWd")
print(elements)
```

it prints nothing, just an empty list []

I can't understand why, I tried `CSS_SELECTOR`, google a lot about it, but couldn't find out, please help...

Comment: This should work, assuming you're on the same url for both calls.  Please post your full code.

Comment: @JohnGordon added full code

Comment: This code does not call both `find_element()` and `find_elements()`, as you said you tried.  Please post your code that calls BOTH of those functions.

Comment: We need to see an example where `find_element()` works but `find_elements()` does not, all in the same code.

Comment: @JohnGordon did it! When I run this code together it works fine, but when i remove find_element it strangely doesn't work... I don't know why!!

Comment: maybe because it doesn't have enough time to load(I guess), but I don't know how to give him enough time to load actually. As i swap the order where I put find functions, it also changes. When I firstly run find_elements it gives an empty list, however when i run find_element first it works completely fine...

Comment: If you can't post a code example that actually demonstrates the issue, then I don't know how to help.

Answer (score 0):

After googling 3 hours, I found out that program didn't have enough time to load the page, so I added

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "rg_i.Q4LuWd")))
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "rg_i.Q4LuWd")
```

And it finally works!